# How to change chart height in hchart() function in R (highcharter package) without using pipe operator?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I built a Shiny app where I create some plot from `hist()` and `density()` objects, both saved in a list into an .RDS file from another script file. So, in shiny I only read the .RDS and make the plot.

Everything is working now, except that I am not finding how to change the height of the highchart plot using the `hchart()` function. In my code, the way it was built, I cannot work with pipes "%>%", beacuse I am using `hchart` inside a `purrr::map()` function.

To explain better I created a small example, that follows.

```
 # Example of how the objects are structured
        list <-
          list(df1 = list(Sepal.Length = hist(iris$Sepal.Length, plot = FALSE)),
               df2 = list(Sepal.Length = density(iris$Sepal.Length)))

 # Example of a plot built with hchart function
        list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% 
        purrr::map(hchart, showInLegend = FALSE)

 # Example of what does not work
        list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% 
        purrr::map(hchart, showInLegend = FALSE, height = 200)
```

Actually, I also would like to change more options of the chart, like colors, for example. But I am not finding a way with this solution I found.

Thanks in advance.

Wlademir.

Comment: Hi @wlademir-ribeiro-prates, question: `list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% purrr::map(hchart, showInLegend = FALSE)` is a list of highcharter charts, right?

Comment: Yes @jbkunst . It is a list. I did this because I create one script to process data and create chart objects. Then I use the output to analyze the results in a shiny app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see 2 main ways to do what you need (not sure why you can't use the pipe):

#### Option 1

Create a function to process every data and add the options inside that function:

```
get_hc <- function(d) {
  hchart(d, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
    hc_size(height= 200) %>%
    hc_title(text = "Purrr rocks")
}
```

Then:

```
 list_of_charts <- list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% 
        purrr::map(get_hc)
```

#### Option 2

You can use successively `purrr::map`:

```
list_of_charts <- list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% 
    purrr::map(hchart, showInLegend = FALSE)

# change heigth
list_of_charts <- purrr::map(list_of_charts, hc_size, height = 200)

# change title
list_of_charts <- purrr::map(list_of_charts, hc_title. text = "Purrr rocks")
```

Or you can use successively `purrr::map`/ `%>%` combo:

```
list_of_charts <- list[['df2']]['Sepal.Length'] %>% 
    purrr::map(hchart, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
    purrr::map(hc_size, height = 200) %>%
    purrr::map(hc_title, text = "Purrr rocks")
```